# Database table details

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to get table information from a database containing following columns:

1. database name
2. table name
3. number of column
4. used space
5. unused space

I have 50 databases and I want this information transfer in excel file

Comment: You need just the number of columns or also the column names?

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the results you are looking for in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    t.max_column_id_used AS Columns,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, t.max_column_id_used
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

If you need all this information transferred and stored in Excel spreadsheets, then you will need to create a SSIS package, with -

1. A Foreach Loop Container
2. A variable which will take the db name as input
3. A data flow task, that will connect to each DB iteratively and execute the above SQL
4. An Excel destination, which will write the results to an Excel spreadsheet.

If you have challenges creating the SSIS package, then you can manually execute this query against each one of your databases and copy/paste the results into Excel. Mind-numbingly boring, but an one-time activity.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but I need to do it for every database....I want in a single query that will give all details regarding all databases and its tables.